# How to make a form in c++ from scratch without winforms?

Tags: c++, forms

I want to make desktop application with cpp and make a completely new form and I don't want to use winforms or any external addons just cpp.

Comment: Then you are probably limited to winapi. The documentation is here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window)

Comment: Please read -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When presenting output to screen you almost always have to call some kind of system call at some point. So the next closest thing to winforms is probably the winapi, but you could try some kind of graphical library for example `sdl2` or `sfml` which encapsulates these calls with their own api. But you wouldn't have all these nice native windows buttons and tabviews and scrollbars and textboxes and ... only some basic shapes, images and pixel buffers

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting to research for these libraries.